# trying to make an "OS" in batch

Tags: batch-file, crash

```
    @echo off
:load
rem imitation of loading the os
color 70
ver
title boot
echo please wait...
ping localhost -n 3 >nul
cls
systeminfo
rem in here user types name he wants to be his account name
:login
title login
cls
date
cls
echo welcome to windows 71
echo before we bigen please type your name
set /P_name=here:
if %name%=admin goto admin
if not goto ms
rem ms=menu start
:ms 
echo %time%
echo hello %name% 
echo type HELP for list to commands
set /P_command=here:
if %command%=help goto help
if %command%=exit goto exit
if %command%=calendar goto cal
if not goto wc
rem wc=wrong command
:admin
echo hello %name% to the admin panel
echo type HELP for list to commands
set /P_command=here:
if %command%=help goto help
if %command%=exit goto exit
if %command%=calendar goto cal
```

So the problem is that it crashes after the `:LOGIN` part and I don't know what to do!

I'm trying to make an OS batch (something like MS-DOS), but it crashes after the "login" part.

I tried everything I could think of and it didn't work, also I want to make a save file so users can set a password for their "account".

Comment: `if  /I "%name%"=="admin"` and you cannot do `if not` without a match statement`

Comment: I would also consider using `choice` instead of the `set /p` and `if` statements.

Comment: Well it certainly will not help if you keep creating variable names, then try to use them without their leading underscores. `%_name%`, `%_command%` and `%_command%` not `%name%`, `%command%` and `%command%`. Please also use this syntax, `Set /P "_command=here:"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in above comments, you need to correctly use your variables, you can however use `choice` instead of `set /p` for your commands.

```
@echo off
:load
rem imitation of loading the os
color 70
ver
title boot
echo please wait...
timeout /t 3 >nul
cls
systeminfo
rem in here user types name he wants to be his account name
:login
title login
cls
date /t
timeout /t 2>nul
cls
echo welcome to windows 71
echo Before we begin please type your name
set /P "_name=here:"
if /i "_%name%"=="admin" goto admin
rem ms=menu start
:ms 
echo %time%
echo hello %_name% 
echo type HELP for list to commands
CHOICE /C HEC /M "Press H for Help, E to exit C for Calender."
goto opt%errorlevel%

:admin
echo hello %_name% to the admin panel
echo type HELP for list to commands
CHOICE /C HEC /M "Press H for Help, E to exit C for Calender."
goto opt%errorlevel%

:opt1
echo Help stuff goes here

goto :eof
:opt2
exit

:opt3
echo Calenders stuff goes here
```

Some things to note. You do not require to goto `ms` is the user is not admin as the statement for not being admin will not be met, we will automatically faal through into the `ms` label.

Notice where the problems were in your code. i.e `if %name%=admin` should be `if "%_name%"=="admin"` with double equal sign and the underscore in the name. It is also double quoted to ensure that we do a match without unwanted whitespace. Lastly `/I` option to catch ADMIN in any case.

See `if /?`, `choice /?` from command line for more help around these functions.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this code is quite wrong.
I fixed it.

```
@echo off
:load
rem imitation of loading the os
color 70
title boot
echo please wait...
ping localhost -n 3 >nul
cls
rem in here user types name he wants to be his account name
:login
title login
cls
echo Welcome to Microsoft Windows 7!
echo Before we begin, please type your name.
set /p name=here:
if "%name%"=="admin" goto admin
if not "%name%"=="admin" goto ms
rem ms=menu start
:ms 
echo %time%
echo Hello %name% 
echo Type HELP for list to commands
set /p command=here:
if "%command%"=="help" goto help
if "%command%"=="exit" goto exit
if "%command%"=="calendar" goto cal
goto ms
rem wc=wrong command
:admin
CLS
echo hello %name% to the admin panel
echo type HELP for list to commands
set /P command=here:
if "%command%"=="help" goto help
if "%command%"=="exit" goto exit
if "%command%"=="calendar" goto cal

GOTO :ADMIN
```

Okay but you don't need to start systeminfo and all that.

Answer (score 0):

This Code May Help.

```
@echo off
:load
::imitation of loading the os
color 70
title boot
echo please wait...
ping localhost -n 3 >nul
cls
systeminfo
::in here user types name he wants to be his account name
:login
title login
cls
%date%
ping localhost -n 2
cls
echo welcome to windows 71
echo before we begin please type your name
set /p _name=here:
if %_name%=admin goto admin
:ms 
echo %time%
echo hello %name% 
echo type HELP for list to commands
set /p command=here:
if %command%=help goto help
if %command%=exit goto exit
if %command%=calendar goto cal
goto wc
::wc=wrong command
:admin
echo hello %name%,welcome to the admin panel
echo type HELP for list to commands
set /p command=here:
if %command%=help goto help
if %command%=exit goto exit
if %command%=calendar goto cal
```